# Warning This method has a constructor name

Tags: java, android, constructor

I am using a class named `A` in android development, this warning pops out when I create a class named:

```
private Intent a() // This method has a constructor name
{
    b.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = b.getDrawingCache();
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
    intent.setType("image/jpg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrayoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
            bytearrayoutputstream);
    File file = new File((new StringBuilder())
            .append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
            .append(File.separator).append("temp_file.jpg").toString());
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fileoutputstream.write(bytearrayoutputstream.toByteArray());
        fileoutputstream.close();
    } catch (IOException ioexception) {
        ioexception.printStackTrace();
    }
    intent.addFlags(0x80000);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", Uri.fromFile(file));
    a.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via: "));
    return intent;
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: This can never happen, when you follow the Java naming conventions ;-)

Answer (score 2):

What @Raghunandan said.

Creating methods named the same as the classname (thus constructor) are apparently not necessarily illegal (warning, no error?), but can be very confusing. Try to come up with a more descriptive name of your method.

Comment: What the hell does your method do?

Comment: poker face :|
means intent ?

Comment: What *kind* of intent? If I were to use your code, I'd like to know what a method does by reading its name, not its contents. Think of something like `createXXXIntent`.

Comment: i used this above the code
`class a
    implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
{

    final ExpandedActivity a;
    private final ImageView b;

    a(ExpandedActivity expandedactivity, ImageView imageview)
    {
     super();
        a = expandedactivity;
        b = imageview;
        
    }
`

Comment: pardon me sir i am new to this :D

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this warning because the Android lint tool (static code analysis tool) that checks your Android project source files for potential bugs and optimization improvements detects a suspicious (but not erroneous) naming here.

You have 3 options, in all cases everything will compile fine and nothing will explode.
I've ordered the options from best to worse.

1. Make everybody happy and change the name
2. Keep using the ridiculous name and ignore the warning
3. Make the warning disappear by adding an @supresswarnings rule above the part where it is giving the warning or adjust the lint settings in your IDE.